# Solving system of nonlinear complex equations in Python

Tags: python, complex-numbers, equation-solving, nonlinear-functions

I'm trying to solve a problem with 8 unknowns and 8 complex equations. I've tried to use `fsolve` but I get the error message:

`error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.`

From what I've now read `fsolve` doesn't support complex equations and hence my questions, how would I solve systems of complex non-linear equations in Python?

PS: I've seen the suggestion to split my problem up into imaginary and real part and use `fsolve` on those separately but that is too cumbersome.

This is the relevant snippet of my code:

```
A=1

def equations(p):
    B,C,D,F,G,H,I,J = p
    return (
        A+B-C-D,
        1j*k0*(A-B)                                   -1j*k1*(C-D),

        B*exp(1j*k1*a1) + D*exp(-1j*k1*a1)            - F*exp(1j*k0*a1) - G*exp(-1j*k0*a1),
        1j*k1* ( C*exp(1j*k1*a1) - D*exp(-1j*k1*a1) ) - 1j*k0*( F*exp(1j*k0*a1) - G*exp(-1j*k0*a1) ),

        F*exp(1j*k0*a1L) + G*exp(-1j*k0*a1L)          - H*exp(-k2*a1L) - I*exp(k2*a1L),
        1j*k0*( F*exp(1j*k0*a1L) - G*exp(-1j*k0*a1L) )- k2*( -H*exp(-k2*a1L) + I*exp(k2*a1L) ),

        H*exp(-k2*a12L) + I*exp(k2*a12L)              - J*exp(1j*k0*a12L),
        k2*( -H*exp(-k2*a12L) + I*exp(k2*a12L) )      - 1j*k0*J*exp(1j*k0*a12L)
    )

B, C, D, F, G, H, I, J = fsolve(equations, (-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1))
```

Comment: What is `fsolve`?

Comment: `scipy.optimize.fsolve` for finding roots of functions ( https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html )

Answer (score 0):

**Algorithm in which the code below was written**
[algorithm for Newton’s Method for Systems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz4Yf.png)

```py
# Author  : Carlos Eduardo da Silva Lima
# Theme   : Newton’s Method for Systems (real or complex)
# Language: Python
# IDE     : Google Colab
# Data    : 18/11/2022

######################################################################
# This Part contains the imports of packages needed for this project #
######################################################################
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.linalg import inv, norm, multi_dot
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

######################
# Enter problem data #
######################
x0  = np.array([1.0+0.0j, 1.0+0.0j, 1.0+0.0j]) # Initial guess for the possible root of the set of nonlinear equations entered in F(x)
TOL = 1e-49                                    # Stipulated minimum tolerance
N   = 10                                       # Number of required maximum iterations

############################
# Newton-Raphson algorithm #
############################
def newtonRapshonSistem(F,J,x0,TOL,N):
  x = x0 # First kick
  k = 1
  while(k<=N):

    # Ccalculation of the product between the inverse of the Jacobian matrix (J(x)^(-1)) and the vector F(x) (T a transpose)
    y = -((inv(J(x)))@(F(x).T))
    x += (y.T)

    # absolute value norm
    erro_abs = np.linalg.norm(np.abs(y))
    if erro_abs<TOL:
      break
    k += 1

  # Exit #
  print(f"Number of iterations: {k}")
  print(f"Absolute error: {erro_abs}\n")
  print("\nSolução\n")
  for l in range(0,np.size(x),1):
    print(f"x[{l}] = {x[l]:.4}\n")
    # print(f'x[{l}] = {np.real(x[l]):.4} + {np.imag(x[l]):.4}j')
  return x
  

#################
# Function F(x) #
#################
def F(x):
  # definition of variables (Arrays)
  x1,x2,x3 = x

  # definition of the set of nonlinear equations
  f1 = x1+x2-10000
  f2 = x1*np.exp(-1j*x3*5) + x2*np.exp(1j*x3*5) - 12000
  f3 = x1*np.exp(-1j*x3*10) + x2*np.exp(1j*x3*10) - 8000

  return np.array([f1, f2, f3], dtype=np.complex128)

############
# Jacobian #
############
def J(x):
  # definition of variables (Arrays)
  x1,x2,x3 = x

  # Jacobean matrix elements
  df1_dx1 = 1
  df1_dx2 = 1
  df1_dx3 = 0

  df2_dx1 = np.exp(-1j*x3*5)
  df2_dx2 = np.exp(1j*x3*5)
  df2_dx3 = x1*(-1j*5)*np.exp(-1j*x3*5)+x2*(1j*5)*np.exp(1j*x3*5)

  df3_dx1 = np.exp(-1j*x3*10)
  df3_dx2 = np.exp(1j*x3*10)
  df3_dx3 = x1*(-1j*10)*np.exp(-1j*x3*10) + x2*(1j*10)*np.exp(1j*x3*10)

  matriz_jacobiana = np.array([
      [df1_dx1, df1_dx2, df1_dx3], 
      [df2_dx1, df2_dx2, df2_dx3], 
      [df3_dx1, df3_dx2, df3_dx3]], dtype=np.complex128)

  return matriz_jacobiana

# Calculate the roots
s = newtonRapshonSistem(F,J,x0,TOL,N)

# Application of the result obtained in x in F.
F(s)
```

Finally! If you don't agree, or if you find any errors, please let me know. In the most I hope to help you and the community the community. Up until :-).